# Firebase - Get firebase data synchronously in for loop?

Tags: java, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to download firebase data in for loop then notify RecyclerView adapter. But since firebase runs async task. I'm not able to do that. How to force firebase to run synchronously or how to know all firebase data is downloaded.

Example code:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(list.get(i)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    //When all data is downloaded
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to force Firebase to read the data synchronously.

But if all you want to do is know when all data has been loaded, you can keep a simple counter of the number of items that successfully loaded:

```
int completedCount = 0;
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(list.get(i)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            completedCount = completedCount + 1;
            if (completedCount == list.size()) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```